# Render 3d area chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, plot

I am trying to plot a 3d area chart using d3.js and following this [link](http://bl.ocks.org/supereggbert/aff58196188816576af0).

My problem is I am not able to understand which algorithm is being used and unable to put axes in the plot as well.

Also the z length is less than x and y length when plotting i.e. say (x,y,z) = (1,1,1) then if x and y length when plotting if is 1cm, z length is way lesser than 1cm as per the above link.

Any help would be appreciated and thanx in advance